# SonicWALL Net Extender, security?

Tags: security, vpn, ssl

I'm new to SonicWALL. How secure is the SonicWALL Net Extender? It seems to be using PTPP, but calls it SSL VPN, are they different. Am I secure? If its bad, whats better?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NetExtender operates over SSL.  It does not use pptp or l2tp although the SonicWALL may also have the capability of becoming an endpoint for l2tp.  That is separate from NetExtender afaict.

Comment: It seems you don't know what it uses, per your comment, perfect chance to research what it does use then edit that into your answer.

Comment: When I said "I don't think" I meant "I know it doesn't".  Pardon me for being wishy-washy.  But some of us are not Sith lords and so do not speak in absolutes.

Comment: If you know it does not, then say you know it does not, "I don't think it uses" indicates you don't know one way or another.

Comment: Clearly you are inordinately invested in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I secure? If its bad, whats better?

Microsoft's PPTP is [unconditionally insecure](https://www.google.com/search?q=ms+pptp+insecure). Use an IPSec or IKEv2 VPN with client certificates for the best security posture. Also, use something like [ike-scan](http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools-resources/security-tools/ike-scan) to verify portions of the configuration.

I also question some of the closed source firewall solutions because they do things like hard-coding passwords for [backdoor] access. See, for example, [Barracuda Firewall Rigged With Hard-Coded Backdoor](http://www.hotforsecurity.com/blog/barracuda-firewall-rigged-with-hard-coded-backdoor-5142.html). I use a [m0n0wall](http://m0n0.ch/wall/index.php) because it built upon the BSDs and it supports IPSec VPNs. Note: this is not an indictment of Sonicwall.

Also see, for example, [PPTP vs L2TP vs OpenVPN vs SSTP vs IKEv2](https://www.bestvpn.com/blog/4147/pptp-vs-l2tp-vs-openvpn-vs-sstp-vs-ikev2/)

Comment: Is the net-extender definitely pptp?

Comment: @wlraider70 - I have no idea; I don't use it. I was commenting on the use of PPTP.

Comment: It's definitely not.